# How to catch the output using TCL expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a tcl file(num.tcl) in remote machine which has 500 line.

```
expect1.9> send ls\r
expect1.10> expect .*
ls
num.tcl
```

1. Using cat command i am viewing that file

> expect1.11> send "cat num.tcl\r"

2. after that i am expecting everything(all 500 lines from top to bottom of the file)

> expect1.12> expect .*

3. when i see `expect_out(buffer)` it consist only first `222 lines`, remaining lines`(224 to 500) are missing`, can anyone clarify me why i am not getting remaining lines, as i know by default it will capture only 2000bytes of data then it will overwrite the new data.

If that is the case i should see the last 2000bytes(lines from the bottom) of data.

And i tried the same with `match_max 100000`(increased expect_out(buffer) size), still i am getting the same output like below

```
expect1.12> expect .*
bgl-xdm-121:130> cat num.tcl
Line number : 1
Line number : 2
Line number : 3
Line number : 4
Line number : 5
Line number : 6
Line number : 7
Line number : 8
Line number : 9
Line number : 10
Line number : 11
Line number : 12
Line number : 13
Line number : 14
Line number : 15
Line number : 16
Line number : 17
Line number : 18
Line number : 19
Line number : 20
Line number : 21
Line number : 22
Line number : 23
Line number : 24
Line number : 25
Line number : 26
Line number : 27
Line number : 28
Line number : 29
Line number : 30
Line number : 31
Line number : 32
Line number : 33
Line number : 34
Line number : 35
Line number : 36
Line number : 37
Line number : 38
Line number : 39
Line number : 40
Line number : 41
Line number : 42
Line number : 43
Line number : 44
Line number : 45
Line number : 46
Line number : 47
Line number : 48
Line number : 49
Line number : 50
Line number : 51
Line number : 52
Line number : 53
Line number : 54
Line number : 55
Line number : 56
Line number : 57
Line number : 58
Line number : 59
Line number : 60
Line number : 61
Line number : 62
Line number : 63
Line number : 64
Line number : 65
Line number : 66
Line number : 67
Line number : 68
Line number : 69
Line number : 70
Line number : 71
Line number : 72
Line number : 73
Line number : 74
Line number : 75
Line number : 76
Line number : 77
Line number : 78
Line number : 79
Line number : 80
Line number : 81
Line number : 82
Line number : 83
Line number : 84
Line number : 85
Line number : 86
Line number : 87
Line number : 88
Line number : 89
Line number : 90
Line number : 91
Line number : 92
Line number : 93
Line number : 94
Line number : 95
Line number : 96
Line number : 97
Line number : 98
Line number : 99
Line number : 100
Line number : 101
Line number : 102
Line number : 103
Line number : 104
Line number : 105
Line number : 106
Line number : 107
Line number : 108
Line number : 109
Line number : 110
Line number : 111
Line number : 112
Line number : 113
Line number : 114
Line number : 115
Line number : 116
Line number : 117
Line number : 118
Line number : 119
Line number : 120
Line number : 121
Line number : 122
Line
```

Comment: Is this performed in local bash shell or in a remote ?

Comment: from the machine A i took ssh session of the same machine(A).

Comment: Instead of using `expect .*`, wait for the terminal prompt, as there is no other means of knowing end of file while we are in remote shell via `Expect`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, In case if i want to capture everything without expecting terminal prompt, is there anyway to do it ? and if i give {expect -re .*} does it will accomplish my requirement .

Comment: Not necessarily. `*` means anything and 'nothing' is also anything. so you will always end-up with undesired result. Waiting for the prompt is the righteous way.

Comment: As you said i expected for terminal prompt now i got all 500 lines, thank you for your inputs. I have another two question, 1. if i run a service in debug mode it will keep on through debug message on stdout in that case we can't expect for terminal prompt in that case how we can overcome the issue 2. if my file has 5000 pages of content, if that is the case how i can get all the output into expect_out(buffer) because by default expect_out(buffer) is capable to hold 2000 bytes, so all 5000 pages cant hold into 2000 bytes of buffer size. kindly let me know how can i do it for above two scenario

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101155/discussion-between-dinesh-and-velpandian).